# PowerShell: replace newline and connect two lines

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, replace, newline

I'm trying to remove the new line on the first match of "three", but I'm not sure why the below example isn't working:

```
$var = 'one two three
four five six
seven'

$var = $var.replace("three`n", 'three ')
$var
```

Desired output:

```
one two three four five six
seven
```

Comment: To potential close voters: The problem _is_ reproducible, namely in script files that use CRLF newlines.

Answer (score 2):

**To account for *variations* in newline (line-break) formats**, use the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) with **[regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `\r?\n`** to match a newline in a platform- / file-format-neutral manner:

```sh
$var = 'one two three
four five six
seven'

$var -replace 'three\r?\n', 'three '
```

The regex `\r?\n` matches both Windows-format CRLF (`\r\n`) and Unix-format LF (`\n` only) newlines.

<sup>The foregoing uses verbatim *regex* escape sequences, which the .NET regex engine underlying the `-replace` operator interprets. Expressed as *PowerShell* escape sequences inside [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`), the newline formats are `` `r`n `` and `` `n ``.

You could also express the last statement as `` $var -replace "three`r?`n", 'three ' ``, but it's generally better to pass *verbatim* strings (`'...'`) to the .NET regex engine, so as to avoid confusion over what PowerShell interprets, up front, vs. what the .NET regex engine interprets.</sup>

Note that it is your *script file's* newline format that determines the newline format of multiline *string literals* in it, so **if your script file uses CRLF newlines, `` "three`n" `` will *not* match, because the LF (`` "`n" ``) in the input string is preceded by a CR (`` "`r" ``).**